# How to find specific value in list objects, bank deposit

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a list of customers who owns three bankaccount each (credit, check, retirement) Each bankaccount is a seperate class, with a seperate withdraw method inside. I choose a person in a list (Visual studio) and can by clicking on them see their bankaccount in another list. Now i want to choose one of their account and deposit Money into it, and it is now i get stuck. The money are just beeing depostit to the first bankaccount in the list(index 0)...

I guess i have to compare the account that the customer want to deposit to with the right objects namn in my list (the right account), but cant figure out how i should write this!

the account could also be in different order so i cant just say saving = [0], check [1], retiremet [2],

This is how i call the method

```
validCustomer = (Customer)lstBankKunder.SelectedItem;

if (radioButtonSaving.IsChecked == true)
{
    savingAccount = new SavingsAccount();
    savingAccount.DepositMoney(299, valdCustomer);
    lstKonton.ItemsSource = null;
    lstKonton.ItemsSource = valdCustomer.myBankAccount;
}
```

And the `SavingsAccount` class

```
public override void DepositMoney(int money, Customer validCustomer)
{
    savingsaccount = new SavingsAccount();
    var item = validCustomer.myBankAccount[savingsaccount.Balance];
    item.Balance += money;
    validCustomer.myBankAccount[savingsaccount.Balance] = item;
}
```

Comment: Michael, I highly recommend you not to mix english with your native language when programming. Names like `lstBankKunder` are not obvious to non-native speakers, and in general consistency is something you should strive for

Comment: It appears your logic is a little bit off. When you call `savingAccount.DepositMoney(299, valdCustomer);` you are then creating another `SavingsAccount` with `savingsaccount = new SavingsAccount();` 
 - You are already working within a `SavingsAccount` so this shouldn't be required. It may help if you supply all your code so people can better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Instead of a List you might use a `Dictionary<string, IAccount>`. The key string will be how you obtain the appropriate account. `accounts["savings"].DepositMoney(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your `DepositMoney` method. You are creating a new savings account, every time the method is called and I guess, that the initial balance is 0. But then you are using this balance to select a bank account:

`valdCustomer.myBankAccount[savingsaccount.Balance]`

With this logic this would always be the first account in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one issue with your code. You are creating unnecessary objects of `SavingsAccount` class at various places.

You haven't shared the code of `Customer` class so I am not sure what is the type of `myBankAccount` property.

You need a good way to select a proper account from the customer's multiple account based on the accounttype and then call deposit or withdraw method on that account.

You can use enum for this. Let say you have an enum `AccountType` as following which identifies the type of account.

```
public enum AccountType
{
    Credit,
    Check,
    Retirement
}
```

And then have a property of `AccountType` in the Account.

```
public class BankAccount
{
    protected double balance;
    protected int accountNumber;
    protected AccountType accountType;

    public BankAccount(int accountNumber, AccountType accountType)
    {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public virtual void DepositMoney(double amount)
    {
        this.balance += amount;
    }

    public virtual void WithdrawMoney(double amount)
    {
        this.balance -= amount;
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return this.balance;
        }
    }

    public AccountType AccountType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.accountType;    
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        output.Append(string.Format("Account Number : {0}{1}", this.accountNumber, Environment.NewLine));
        output.Append(string.Format("Account Type : {0}{1}", this.accountType, Environment.NewLine));
        output.Append(string.Format("Account Balance : {0}{1}", this.balance, Environment.NewLine));

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in Customer class you can have `List` of accounts to represent the accounts belonging to that customer.

```
public class Customer
{
    private List<BankAccount> accounts;

    public Customer()
    {
        this.accounts = new List<BankAccount>();
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}   

    public List<BankAccount> Accounts
    {
        get

        {
            return this.accounts;   
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();

        output.Append(string.Format("Customer Name : {0}{1}", this.Name, Environment.NewLine));
        output.Append(string.Format("Accounts details {0}", Environment.NewLine));

        foreach(var account in this.accounts)
        {
            output.Append(account.ToString());
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then you can locate specific type of account of customer  and perform deposit or withdraw operation on it as following.

```
var checkAccount = customer.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(acct => acct.AccountType == AccountType.Check);
if(checkAccount != null)
{
    checkAccount.DepositMoney(3000);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` is an extension method which is part of LINQ. You need to add `using System.Linq;` in the using directives of the code file whereever you are using it.

Note : The names of class, methods and properties are different in my answer then your class names.

I hope this helps you resolve your issue.

EDIT : Edited the answer to have List of accounts in Customer class instead of Dictionary.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the help. The deposit method seems to work with your code. I didn´t write it before but myBankAccount property is a list. Have just been programming for a couple of months so i havent used Dictionary Before. Tryed to change to this instead of List but couldnt figure it out. How can I fix the problem if i stil l want to keep my list? (instead of Dictionary)

Comment: You can use List also. LINQ is the feature offered by C# which you need to use to locate a particular account from a list of account. I updated the answer to use List instead of Dictionary.